# Volume of the solid bounded by $x+y=1$ and $z=4-x^2-4y^2$ and $z=0$ and the coordinated planes

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

$x+y=1$ and $z=4-x^2-4y^2$ how do I set the limits of integration for the integral $$\iint_D 4-x^2-4y^2 dA$$

As I know I have and ellipsoid and a plane not sure of how to get $y$ or $x$ especially in the ellipsoid form because I will just have one side (positive or negative) of the plane xy.

The integration zone is the one that contains the origin

Comment: It's very useful to draw the surfaces and then the intersection curves. You need to find the intersection curves of the plane and the ellipsoid at the plane $z=0$ (a line and a ellipse) and then, the two intersection points for the ellipse and the line. These points set the integration limits for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It is not an ellipsoid. It is a paraboloid. Also, I'm not sure if this is what you meant in your original post, but this seems ambiguous. The plane $x+y=1$ cuts the paraboloid into 2 sections. It is not clear which section is meant (although they may have the same volume by symmetry).

Comment: @Nick True, it's a paraboloid. Anyway, the two parts you talk about are not symetrical.

Comment: @ Rafa Yes you are right. It's not symmetrical. So I think it is not clear which region is meant.